# Use Maximum Likelihood Estimation to guess which dice got selected

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

> We have two six-sided dice (faces numbered 1 through 6) and two tetrahedral dice (faces numbered 1 through 4). Someone selects two of them and throws each once. Then they tell us the sum of the eyes is 7. Estimate which two they selected by using the maximum likelihood principle.

This is a problem on an old probability theory exam. Unfortunately we only ever calculated pretty straightforward examples in class and I have no idea how to tackle this one. However, since the expected value for the sum of the eyes of two six-sided dice is $7$ I guess they likely selected both of these! How can we approach this problem?

Comment: *The eyes* do not make much sense for many [tetrahedral dice](https://www.google.com/search?q=tetrahedral+dice&tbm=isch&gws_rd=cr) as there is no upper face

Comment: Thanks for the remark, Henry. I guess what is meant here is that each face has a certain number of dots and the result of throwing a tetrahedral die is the number of dots of the hidden face. I will edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

- What is the probability of a sum of $7$ from two six-sided dice?
- What is the probability of a sum of $7$ from two four-sided dice?

Comment: The two probabilities are $\frac{1}{6}$ and $\frac{1}{8}$. But I'm confused as to how I can combine these into a likelihood function of some sort. In all examples I've seen all "observations" came from the same probability space/had the same distribution, but in this case we have $\Omega_1 = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2$ and $\Omega_2 = \{1,2,3,4\}^2$. This is a great source of confusion.

Comment: I would say the likelihoods were proportional to $\frac16$ and $\frac18$ and so the former was larger.

Comment: Thanks, Henry. But can you maybe elaborate on how you would proceed to obtain a likelihood function from this information? I'm mostly interested in how to model this specific problem in a MLE fashion. The actual solution is not that important to me.

Comment: As far as I am aware, you simply use $\mathcal{L}(\theta |x) \propto  P(x | \theta)$, where $\theta$ here is the numbers of sides on each of the two dice.  So the likelihood function is proportional to the probability of getting $7$ from two dice with $\theta$ sides each.